# Relative popularity of different languages for machine learning?

Tags: language-agnostic, matrix, programming-languages, machine-learning

By asking for the 'relative popularity' of different languages, rather than asking 'what is the best language?' or 'what is your favorite language', I hope to make this somewhat objective.

I want a language for machine learning / matrices, that is:

- opensource-friendly (cf matlab)
- fast for inner-loops (cf python,matlab)
- fast for matrices (most languages are about the same, since they can usually use BLAS)
- has terse, easy to read syntax (cf java)

I've currently settled on java, since it's average at everything, but really poor at nothing, but I can't help feeling that java feels more and more dated, eg no operator overloading, and the borked generics, so I'm wondering what the feeling on the relative popularity of different languages for machine learning is?

I *think* mostly people use C++, matlab and python, but just curious if there's some language that I've missed that everyone's busy using, that I didn't realize yet?

Comment: Check your mail hugh! small world. This question will be closed (Sent via linkedin)

Comment: From my experience - you should also think of how well this language will integrate with the web-app or other front-end interfaces which you might later want to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I worked on a machine learning project with a friend, I picked up [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming%20language%29), which is open source, designed for matrix math, and has extensive library support. It's certainly terser than Java, and I found the syntax pleasant, but that's a subjective judgement.

[According to Rexer Analytics](http://www.rexeranalytics.com/Data-Miner-Survey-Results-2011.html), R is the most popular data mining tool, being used by almost half of all of their survey respondents.

(Information on R is hard to search for, so they have a [Google frontend for searching for information about it](http://rseek.org/).)

Comment: Ok, what's R like for speed?  ie, if you have a tight inner loop, is it more like matlab/python or more like c++/java?

Comment: I don't have any other experience to compare it to, but it felt pretty good. I believe that a lot of the libraries are implemented in Fortran, which is reputed to be excellent to matrix math sort of stuff.